# Eureka forms dynamic values

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I want to set my the values of my fields dynamically based on the input I get from an API call.
So for this I get the answers from the server, parse it to objects and I'm trying to set the value.
However this is impossible because the rowBy(tag:) method returns a BaseRow so I don't know what type the row is. And a BaseRow doesn't have the parameter value.

Is there a known method that allows me to check what field type it is and set the value?

```
ItemProducer.itemGetFormAnswers(withArguments: arguments) { (success, responseData, error) in

```
MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
switch(success) {
case .responseTrue:
    for dataObject in responseData?["data"] as! [[AnyHashable:Any]] {
        let answerObject = Answer.parseJSON(dataObject)
        if (answerObject != nil) {
            self.answers[(answerObject?.questionID)!] = answerObject

            //Add answer
            if let row = self.form.rowBy(tag: String(describing: answerObject?.questionID)) {
                let date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: Double((answerObject?.answer)!)!)
                row.value = date
                row.reload()
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
    break
default:
    print("failed to get the answers")
    break
}
```

}```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check for a specific class?

```
if myObject is MyClass {
    // myObject is of type MyClass
}
```

Thus you could also try in more detail:

```
guard let _ : MyRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: String(describing: answerObject?.questionID)) else {
                        // do your logic
                        return
                    }
```

If you don't know what kind of json obkject you have serialized in your dict, you could check for specific attributes like this:

```
if let mySpecificAttribute = answerObject["mySpecificAttribute "] as? String {
    // answerObject got a value for key "mySpecificAttribute "
}
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that but the method rowBy returns an BaseRow class that can be typecast to different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with a ledger idea. I knew that this was an option but I hoped that Eureka had a more advanced option. For people interested in the execution of the idea I did the following.

```
`
//Loop through all the questions
for question in self.arrQuestions {
    switch(question.detailType) {
    case .checkBox:
        if let answerObject = self.answers[question.questionID] {
            let row = self.form.rowBy(tag: String(describing: answerObject.questionID)) as! CheckRow
            row.value = Bool(answerObject.answer)
            row.reload()
        }
        break
    case .dateTime:
        if let answerObject = self.answers[question.questionID] {
            let row = self.form.rowBy(tag: String(describing: answerObject.questionID)) as! DateTimeRow
            let date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: Double((answerObject.answer)!)!)
            row.value = date
            row.reload()
        }
        break
        ...... etc......
`
```